# Does the DomContentLoaded event imply construction of DOM tree or render tree?

Tags: javascript, html

When I profile my app the event is raise 1.5 second but the first pixels appear much later. This could imply that the event only stands for DOM tree construction. But this tutorial has me slightly confused now

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/analyzing-crp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, `without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading`.

[MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)

Comment: This doesn’t really relate to rendering, which is another separate step.

Comment: The browser starts rendering the page right after the first HTML element is parsed. It certainly doesn't wait for the DOM tree to be completed, far less for all the external resources to load.

Comment: Is there event to signal the constrcution of render tree ? I dont care about images so load event is not useful for me

Answer (score -1):

i have encountered the same question, so i read the article in google developers that you provide. However, i came into a different conclusion that it implies DOMContentLoaded event fires when dom tree is ready without waiting for cssom and render tree.
here is something from that article:

```
*An asynchronous script has several advantages:
The script is no longer parser blocking and is not part of the critical rendering path.
Because there are no other critical scripts, the CSS doesn't need to block the domContentLoaded event.
The sooner the domContentLoaded event fires, the sooner other application logic can begin executing.*
```

which means if script don't stop domtree parsing by set "async", domcontentloaded event won't even wait for css loading nor parsing to cssom.